# FFMPEG does not produce output a valid mp4 when called from Java

Tags: java, ffmpeg, ubuntu-18.04

I am merging an image with an audio file into a mp4-video using the ffmpeg-command:

```
ffmpeg -y -r 30 -loop 1 -i <path/to/image.png> -i <path/to/audio.aac> -shortest -acodec copy -vcodec libx264 <path/to/output.mp4>
```

To call this command from Java I'm using this code:

```
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("ffmpeg", "-y", "-r",
                    String.valueOf(generalConfig.getOutputFPS()), "-loop", "1", "-i", pictureFile,
                    "-i", transspoken.getVoiceFile(), "-shortest", "-acodec", "copy", "-vcodec", "libx264",
                    snippetOut);
builder.redirectOutput(new File(getTMPName() + ".txt"));
builder.redirectError(new File(getTMPName() + ".txt"));
builder.redirectErrorStream(true);

LogUtils.debug("FFMPEG-Render", String.join(" ", builder.command()));
try {
    Process p = builder.start();
    p.waitFor();
} catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This code runs without problem on my local machine running Ubuntu 18.04 Desktop and OpenJDK 11.0.4. However, when run on a Ubuntu 18.04 Server droplet, running the same OpenJDK-Version, the code results in a corrupted output. Strangely, there is absolutely no problem when I ssh into the server and call exactly the same command to generate the mp4 file. So I am in a the really strange situation where:

1. The command works fine when called automatically on my local machine.
2. The command works fine when called manually on the server.
3. The command does not work when called automatically on the server.

Output of the automated FFMPEG call on the server:

```
 ffmpeg version 3.4.6-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 7 (Ubuntu 7.3.0-16ubuntu3)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.18.04.1 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librubberband --enable-librsvg --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libopencv --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  libavutil      55. 78.100 / 55. 78.100
  libavcodec     57.107.100 / 57.107.100
  libavformat    57. 83.100 / 57. 83.100
  libavdevice    57. 10.100 / 57. 10.100
  libavfilter     6.107.100 /  6.107.100
  libavresample   3.  7.  0 /  3.  7.  0
  libswscale      4.  8.100 /  4.  8.100
  libswresample   2.  9.100 /  2.  9.100
  libpostproc    54.  7.100 / 54.  7.100
[png_pipe @ 0x560225784a60] Stream #0: not enough frames to estimate rate; consider increasing probesize
Input #0, png_pipe, from 'tmp/render_1.png':
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: png, rgb24(pc), 1920x1080, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
[aac @ 0x560225789940] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
Input #1, aac, from 'tmp/marytts_1.aac':
  Duration: 00:00:04.80, bitrate: 25 kb/s
    Stream #1:0: Audio: aac (LC), 16000 Hz, mono, fltp, 25 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (png (native) -> h264 (libx264))
  Stream #1:0 -> #0:1 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[libx264 @ 0x56022578c2e0] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 BMI2 AVX2 AVX512
[libx264 @ 0x56022578c2e0] profile High 4:4:4 Predictive, level 4.0, 4:4:4 8-bit
[libx264 @ 0x56022578c2e0] 264 - core 152 r2854 e9a5903 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2017 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x1:0x111 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=0 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=4 threads=1 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to 'tmp/render_2.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf57.83.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv444p, 1920x1080, q=-1--1, 30 fps, 15360 tbn, 30 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.107.100 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
    Stream #0:1: Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 16000 Hz, mono, fltp, 25 kb/s
frame=    6 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=   0x    
frame=   12 fps= 11 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=   0x    
frame=   18 fps= 11 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=   0x    
frame=   23 fps= 10 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=   0x    
frame=   27 fps=9.8 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=   0x    
frame=   30 fps=9.2 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=   0x    
frame=   32 fps=7.9 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=   0x    
frame=   33 fps=7.1 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=   0x    
frame=   34 fps=6.4 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=   0x    
frame=   35 fps=5.4 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=   0x    
frame=   38 fps=5.4 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=   0x    
frame=   42 fps=5.0 q=29.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=   0x
```

The error output is empty. FFProbe on the corrupted file:

```
$ ffprobe tmp/render_2.mp4
    ffprobe version 3.4.6-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 Copyright (c) 2007-2019 the FFmpeg developers
      built with gcc 7 (Ubuntu 7.3.0-16ubuntu3)
      configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.18.04.1 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librubberband --enable-librsvg --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libopencv --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
      libavutil      55. 78.100 / 55. 78.100
      libavcodec     57.107.100 / 57.107.100
      libavformat    57. 83.100 / 57. 83.100
      libavdevice    57. 10.100 / 57. 10.100
      libavfilter     6.107.100 /  6.107.100
      libavresample   3.  7.  0 /  3.  7.  0
      libswscale      4.  8.100 /  4.  8.100
      libswresample   2.  9.100 /  2.  9.100
      libpostproc    54.  7.100 / 54.  7.100
    [mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x558b07498080] moov atom not found
    tmp/render_2.mp4: Invalid data found when processing input
```

At first I thought that the java program is not properly waiting for FFMpeg to finish thereby causing the corrupted output but some time measurements made me somewhat confident that that is not the cause of this bug.

EDIT:

Output of the ffmpeg command on the server when called via ssh:

```
$ ffmpeg -y -r 30 -loop 1 -i tmp/render_1.png -i tmp/marytts_1.aac -shortest -acodec copy -vcodec libx264 tmp/render_2.mp4
ffmpeg version 3.4.6-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 7 (Ubuntu 7.3.0-16ubuntu3)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.18.04.1 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librubberband --enable-librsvg --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libopencv --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  libavutil      55. 78.100 / 55. 78.100
  libavcodec     57.107.100 / 57.107.100
  libavformat    57. 83.100 / 57. 83.100
  libavdevice    57. 10.100 / 57. 10.100
  libavfilter     6.107.100 /  6.107.100
  libavresample   3.  7.  0 /  3.  7.  0
  libswscale      4.  8.100 /  4.  8.100
  libswresample   2.  9.100 /  2.  9.100
  libpostproc    54.  7.100 / 54.  7.100
[png_pipe @ 0x562e37a77a60] Stream #0: not enough frames to estimate rate; consider increasing probesize
Input #0, png_pipe, from 'tmp/render_1.png':
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: png, rgb24(pc), 1920x1080, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
[aac @ 0x562e37a7c940] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
Input #1, aac, from 'tmp/marytts_1.aac':
  Duration: 00:00:04.80, bitrate: 25 kb/s
    Stream #1:0: Audio: aac (LC), 16000 Hz, mono, fltp, 25 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (png (native) -> h264 (libx264))
  Stream #1:0 -> #0:1 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[libx264 @ 0x562e37a7f2e0] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 BMI2 AVX2 AVX512
[libx264 @ 0x562e37a7f2e0] profile High 4:4:4 Predictive, level 4.0, 4:4:4 8-bit
[libx264 @ 0x562e37a7f2e0] 264 - core 152 r2854 e9a5903 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2017 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x1:0x111 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=0 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=4 threads=1 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to 'tmp/render_2.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf57.83.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv444p, 1920x1080, q=-1--1, 30 fps, 15360 tbn, 30 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.107.100 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
    Stream #0:1: Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 16000 Hz, mono, fltp, 25 kb/s
frame=  194 fps= 10 q=29.0 Lsize=     280kB time=00:00:05.00 bitrate= 458.3kbits/s speed=0.261x    
video:261kB audio:15kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 1.337588%
[libx264 @ 0x562e37a7f2e0] frame I:1     Avg QP:16.02  size:255181
[libx264 @ 0x562e37a7f2e0] frame P:49    Avg QP:10.58  size:    93
[libx264 @ 0x562e37a7f2e0] frame B:144   Avg QP:13.67  size:    69
[libx264 @ 0x562e37a7f2e0] consecutive B-frames:  1.0%  0.0%  0.0% 99.0%
[libx264 @ 0x562e37a7f2e0] mb I  I16..4: 49.3%  0.0% 50.7%
[libx264 @ 0x562e37a7f2e0] mb P  I16..4:  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  P16..4:  0.1%  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:99.9%
[libx264 @ 0x562e37a7f2e0] mb B  I16..4:  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  B16..8:  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  direct: 0.0%  skip:100.0%  L0: 0.0% L1:100.0% BI: 0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x562e37a7f2e0] coded y,u,v intra: 49.6% 41.1% 42.4% inter: 0.0% 0.0% 0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x562e37a7f2e0] i16 v,h,dc,p: 97%  0%  2%  1%
[libx264 @ 0x562e37a7f2e0] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 22% 15%  7%  7%  9% 10%  9%  9% 11%
[libx264 @ 0x562e37a7f2e0] Weighted P-Frames: Y:0.0% UV:0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x562e37a7f2e0] ref P L0: 72.6% 13.6% 11.6%  2.3%
[libx264 @ 0x562e37a7f2e0] kb/s:333.64
```

Output of local automated call:

```
ffmpeg version 3.4.6-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 7 (Ubuntu 7.3.0-16ubuntu3)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.18.04.1 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librubberband --enable-librsvg --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libopencv --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  WARNING: library configuration mismatch
  avcodec     configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.18.04.1 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librubberband --enable-librsvg --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libopencv --enable-libx264 --enable-shared --enable-version3 --disable-doc --disable-programs --enable-libopencore_amrnb --enable-libopencore_amrwb --enable-libtesseract --enable-libvo_amrwbenc
  libavutil      55. 78.100 / 55. 78.100
  libavcodec     57.107.100 / 57.107.100
  libavformat    57. 83.100 / 57. 83.100
  libavdevice    57. 10.100 / 57. 10.100
  libavfilter     6.107.100 /  6.107.100
  libavresample   3.  7.  0 /  3.  7.  0
  libswscale      4.  8.100 /  4.  8.100
  libswresample   2.  9.100 /  2.  9.100
  libpostproc    54.  7.100 / 54.  7.100
[png_pipe @ 0x558d89df15c0] Stream #0: not enough frames to estimate rate; consider increasing probesize
Input #0, png_pipe, from 'tmp/render_1.png':
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: png, rgb24(pc), 1920x1080, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
[aac @ 0x558d89df64a0] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
Input #1, aac, from 'tmp/marytts_1.aac':
  Duration: 00:00:04.80, bitrate: 25 kb/s
    Stream #1:0: Audio: aac (LC), 16000 Hz, mono, fltp, 25 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (png (native) -> h264 (libx264))
  Stream #1:0 -> #0:1 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[libx264 @ 0x558d89df8e40] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 BMI2 AVX2
[libx264 @ 0x558d89df8e40] profile High 4:4:4 Predictive, level 4.0, 4:4:4 8-bit
[libx264 @ 0x558d89df8e40] 264 - core 152 r2854 e9a5903 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2017 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x1:0x111 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=0 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=4 threads=6 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to 'tmp/render_2.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf57.83.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv444p, 1920x1080, q=-1--1, 30 fps, 15360 tbn, 30 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.107.100 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
    Stream #0:1: Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 16000 Hz, mono, fltp, 25 kb/s
frame=   29 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=   0x    
frame=   51 fps= 51 q=29.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=   0x    
frame=   67 fps= 44 q=29.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.51 bitrate=   0.8kbits/s speed=0.335x    
frame=   88 fps= 43 q=29.0 size=     256kB time=00:00:01.21 bitrate=1724.9kbits/s speed=0.595x    
frame=  111 fps= 43 q=29.0 size=     256kB time=00:00:01.93 bitrate=1084.9kbits/s speed=0.756x    
frame=  132 fps= 43 q=29.0 size=     256kB time=00:00:02.68 bitrate= 780.3kbits/s speed=0.877x    
frame=  153 fps= 43 q=29.0 size=     256kB time=00:00:03.39 bitrate= 618.4kbits/s speed=0.949x    
frame=  176 fps= 43 q=29.0 size=     256kB time=00:00:04.16 bitrate= 504.2kbits/s speed=1.02x    
frame=  196 fps= 43 q=29.0 size=     256kB time=00:00:04.80 bitrate= 437.0kbits/s speed=1.04x    
frame=  203 fps= 38 q=29.0 Lsize=     280kB time=00:00:05.00 bitrate= 458.0kbits/s speed=0.946x    
video:261kB audio:15kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 1.338639%
[libx264 @ 0x558d89df8e40] frame I:1     Avg QP:16.02  size:255033
[libx264 @ 0x558d89df8e40] frame P:51    Avg QP:10.50  size:    91
[libx264 @ 0x558d89df8e40] frame B:151   Avg QP:13.67  size:    69
[libx264 @ 0x558d89df8e40] consecutive B-frames:  0.5%  1.0%  0.0% 98.5%
[libx264 @ 0x558d89df8e40] mb I  I16..4: 49.4%  0.0% 50.6%
[libx264 @ 0x558d89df8e40] mb P  I16..4:  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  P16..4:  0.1%  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:99.9%
[libx264 @ 0x558d89df8e40] mb B  I16..4:  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  B16..8:  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  direct: 0.0%  skip:100.0%  L0: 0.0% L1:100.0% BI: 0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x558d89df8e40] coded y,u,v intra: 49.6% 41.1% 42.2% inter: 0.0% 0.0% 0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x558d89df8e40] i16 v,h,dc,p: 97%  0%  2%  1%
[libx264 @ 0x558d89df8e40] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 22% 15%  7%  7%  9% 10%  9% 10% 11%
[libx264 @ 0x558d89df8e40] Weighted P-Frames: Y:0.0% UV:0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x558d89df8e40] ref P L0: 80.5% 10.5%  8.7%  0.3%
[libx264 @ 0x558d89df8e40] kb/s:319.34
```

Output of local manual call:

```
$ ffmpeg -y -r 30 -loop 1 -i tmp/render_1.png -i tmp/marytts_1.aac -shortest -acodec copy -vcodec libx264 tmp/render_2.mp4
ffmpeg version 3.4.6-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 7 (Ubuntu 7.3.0-16ubuntu3)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.18.04.1 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librubberband --enable-librsvg --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libopencv --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  WARNING: library configuration mismatch
  avcodec     configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.18.04.1 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librubberband --enable-librsvg --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libopencv --enable-libx264 --enable-shared --enable-version3 --disable-doc --disable-programs --enable-libopencore_amrnb --enable-libopencore_amrwb --enable-libtesseract --enable-libvo_amrwbenc
  libavutil      55. 78.100 / 55. 78.100
  libavcodec     57.107.100 / 57.107.100
  libavformat    57. 83.100 / 57. 83.100
  libavdevice    57. 10.100 / 57. 10.100
  libavfilter     6.107.100 /  6.107.100
  libavresample   3.  7.  0 /  3.  7.  0
  libswscale      4.  8.100 /  4.  8.100
  libswresample   2.  9.100 /  2.  9.100
  libpostproc    54.  7.100 / 54.  7.100
[png_pipe @ 0x558ddf2165c0] Stream #0: not enough frames to estimate rate; consider increasing probesize
Input #0, png_pipe, from 'tmp/render_1.png':
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: png, rgb24(pc), 1920x1080, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
[aac @ 0x558ddf21b4a0] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
Input #1, aac, from 'tmp/marytts_1.aac':
  Duration: 00:00:04.80, bitrate: 25 kb/s
    Stream #1:0: Audio: aac (LC), 16000 Hz, mono, fltp, 25 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (png (native) -> h264 (libx264))
  Stream #1:0 -> #0:1 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[libx264 @ 0x558ddf21de40] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 BMI2 AVX2
[libx264 @ 0x558ddf21de40] profile High 4:4:4 Predictive, level 4.0, 4:4:4 8-bit
[libx264 @ 0x558ddf21de40] 264 - core 152 r2854 e9a5903 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2017 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x1:0x111 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=0 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=4 threads=6 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to 'tmp/render_2.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf57.83.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv444p, 1920x1080, q=-1--1, 30 fps, 15360 tbn, 30 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.107.100 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
    Stream #0:1: Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 16000 Hz, mono, fltp, 25 kb/s
frame=  203 fps= 40 q=29.0 Lsize=     280kB time=00:00:05.00 bitrate= 458.0kbits/s speed=0.986x    
video:261kB audio:15kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 1.338639%
[libx264 @ 0x558ddf21de40] frame I:1     Avg QP:16.02  size:255033
[libx264 @ 0x558ddf21de40] frame P:51    Avg QP:10.50  size:    91
[libx264 @ 0x558ddf21de40] frame B:151   Avg QP:13.67  size:    69
[libx264 @ 0x558ddf21de40] consecutive B-frames:  0.5%  1.0%  0.0% 98.5%
[libx264 @ 0x558ddf21de40] mb I  I16..4: 49.4%  0.0% 50.6%
[libx264 @ 0x558ddf21de40] mb P  I16..4:  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  P16..4:  0.1%  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:99.9%
[libx264 @ 0x558ddf21de40] mb B  I16..4:  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  B16..8:  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  direct: 0.0%  skip:100.0%  L0: 0.0% L1:100.0% BI: 0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x558ddf21de40] coded y,u,v intra: 49.6% 41.1% 42.2% inter: 0.0% 0.0% 0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x558ddf21de40] i16 v,h,dc,p: 97%  0%  2%  1%
[libx264 @ 0x558ddf21de40] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 22% 15%  7%  7%  9% 10%  9% 10% 11%
[libx264 @ 0x558ddf21de40] Weighted P-Frames: Y:0.0% UV:0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x558ddf21de40] ref P L0: 80.5% 10.5%  8.7%  0.3%
[libx264 @ 0x558ddf21de40] kb/s:319.34
```

Comment: What are the other 3 ffmpeg outputs (terminal local, Java local, terminal server)?

Comment: @levantpied I added them as edit.

Comment: I see you have `e.printStackTrace()` instead of logging. Were you able to confirm it's not throwing an exception here (e.g. by logging something after `p.waitFor`) and actually finishing (e.g. by logging something after the whole `try` / `catch`)?

Comment: I can confirm that there is no Exception thrown.

Comment: "Turning it off and on again" (rebooting the server) sadly also didn't work :(

Comment: Are you able to confirm it finishes as well (i.e. goes after `try` / `catch`)? One more suggestion - try making a `.sh` that runs `ffmpeg` and run that from Java. That way you can make sure you log things there as well (mainly start / exit conditions).

Comment: @levantpied Turns out the server had enough RAM to support FFMpeg on it's own but not the JVM and FFMpeg.

Comment: Glad you solved it!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the server had enough RAM to let the FFMpeg-command run on it's own but not enough RAM to support both the JVM and FFMpeg. This lead to the strange situation described above. I guess the missing RAM then also lead to the error message not being redirected to the file (or FFMpeg fails silently on missing RAM).

I solved the issue add some SWAP-space. You otherwise could upgrade the server.